# How to make a contextual filter optional

Tags: views, panels

I'm making a contextual filter, to pass along an argument from a panel to a view, using `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`.

This is so that it pulls in a keyword from a URL.

However, I want it to work so that when no keyword is passed in, it goes based on the last URL parameter.

For example:

www.example.com/tech/startup

It should pull ONLY things with both tech and startup if this is passed.

However, if the URL is just:

www.example.com/tech

Then it should show ALL articles with the tech taxonomy term.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Exceptions setting in views like below

[image]

And point your menu link to www.example.com/tech/all instead of www.example.com/tech

Comment: Working fine. 
Is there any option to avoid all option?